# Increase number of Loop Cuts - Apple Magic Mouse

Tags: edit-mode

how can I increase the number of Loop Cuts with my Apple Magic Mouse. Normally it is with the scroll wheel, but that does not work with the Magic Mouse.
And I know that I can change the number of cuts afterwards, but sometimes the cuts then are unproportional. Even if I set the cut right in the middle by clicking the left mouse button.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the keyboard (both the top row and the numpad work) to type the number of cuts.

The current number of cuts is displayed in the *Header*, where you can also see the result of [modal numinput expressions](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/UI#Modal_Numinput) (modal numinput will be added in 2.7, and is already in development versions):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't give you smooth scroll control, but if you still want to control the loop cuts from the Magic Mouse, you can use the MagicPrefs app (http://magicprefs.com) to map One Finger Tap Left to the + key and One Finger Tap Right to the - key. This allows you to inc/dec the loop cuts by tapping on the magic mouse. Not as slick but I think it's better than moving your hand to the keyboard.

Additionally if the mapping causes issues in other apps, you can apply the mapping just to Blender itself in MagicPrefs.

[image: Magic Pref Config]

Answer (score 1):

It works fine with my MM but you can always use the + - on the NUM pad

Comment: i have an apple wireless keyboard which has no numpad. What do you mean with MM? Middle Mouse Button?

Comment: Use asked about the Magic Mouse so MM

Comment: Okay if you only have the bluetooth kb use the FN Key and up down arrows.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Do you maybe know why it the MM does not work for me? Maybe because i have different user preferences?

Comment: Couldn't say, but it could be.