# How do I add a specific number of loop cuts?

Tags: modeling, shortcut

I know you can add a loop cut using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, but I want to know how to specify **how many** to add, i.e. add 15 loop cuts to a plane. I know you can manually use the scroll wheel to get this number, however this can be quite tedious.

Related: [Increase number of Loop Cuts - Apple Magic Mouse](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/increase-number-of-loop-cuts-apple-magic-mouse)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this simply by typing the desired number (1 then 5) **after** pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and **before** left-clicking to complete the operation.

Answer (score 8):

And for the sake of completeness:

You can also use the controls on the toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>)

[image]

Or using <kbd>F6</kbd> will bring a pop-up window with the tool's options:

[image]